# Xcode stupid warning: View is clipping its content

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, interface-builder, warnings

I get this stupid warning in Xcode 4

```
Clipped Content
View is clipping its content
```

if I create an unbordered bevel button with an image bigger then the button itself.
Why? How can i suppress it?

Answer (score 52):

I had a similar problem with a gray warning.

> "Warning:  Clipped Content.  View is clipping its content in
>   `XXXX.xib`"

I got rid of the warning by right clicking on `XXXX.xib` > `Open As` > `Source Code`.

After building again in xcode the warning was gone.

Comment: I find it by accident.I think it maybe a bug of xcode.What's Your opinion。

Comment: Still happening in Xcode 9... and still fixed this way.

Comment: This answer works.  Note that if IB errors don't go away even after you have fixed their cause, and rebuilding also doesn't make them go away, quitting and restarting Xcode often helps.  It would be nice if Apple would pay more attention to these issues, IB in Xcode has had these problems for a really long time.

Comment: This did NOT fix it for Xcode 10.1 with Mojave os. It appears for all the TextField items. This didn't happen in my previous Xcode version.

Comment: Xcode 10.2.1 and Mojave : the warnings are back when you reopen the XIB files.

Comment: Just happened to me on an old project I was updating to Xcode 11.3 on Catalina. Open as Source Code followed by opening another xib file than back eliminated the warning.

Comment: It's like a huge game of Whack-a-mole with XCode 12.5. Fix one and two more pop up. I would give XCode 13.2 a spin, but the download time is ~41 hours. Hey Tim, a little less emojis to make people feel good about themselves and a little more testing your software.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Change scaling according to your requirement. It will solve it.

Comment: Thanks, This worked in Xcode 7.3. still stupid xcode.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know you can't suppress specific xib notices, but you can disable them in general. in project->settings (or target->settings if you have multiple targets and only want to do it for one/some), there is the "Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options" section which includes "Show Notices". if you set this to No then you should stop seeing this message. of course, it may mean you miss out on other messages.

Comment: hmm, that's odd - i've got the same thing with one of my xibs and disabling notices does the trick. did you try disabling them in the target settings rather than project settings?

Comment: There is no "Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options" in XCode 4.4. How can I disable all notices?

Comment: @TheFox you should find that at project -> Build Settings. there is Interface Builder XIC Compiler - Options there . FYI I also use XCode 4.4

Comment: @TheFox search for "Show Notices" on that, and should be there

Comment: @arufian What should I say... It's not there. I don't know what's wrong with my XCode. http://img.fox21.at/apple/xcode/xcode-4.5.1_20121009.png

Comment: @TheFox I had some experiments, and now I know what the reason why it was not showing on yours. I guess you only have MainMenu.xib, so try to create new xib file then that options will be show automatically on Build Settings

Comment: @arufian YES! Now I have this options. Thx a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I finally ended up resizing the image because it was so annoying.

Comment: Agreed - easiest thing to do is just change sizes to eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Nothing helps, but add the complaining NSButton again, same wires and bindings and image in same size (scaling down), problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 10.2.1 what solved my problem was to choose Position Below, on Interface Builder, as shown in these pictures, under Show the Attributes inspector tab:

[image]

[image]