# View is clipping its content

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder, warnings

I have a warning in Xcode about clipped content which will not go away. I've looked at the following questions and answers: [Xcode stupid warning: View is clipping its content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8597189), and [View is Clipping its Content error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20353708)) but this issue is different in the scope of what is mentioned for possible solutions.

The main problem is that nothing in the `IB` gains focus or becomes highlighted when clicking onto the warning, so I have no idea where the clipped content actually is...

*Warning in Xcode 9.x:*

```
MainMenu.nib: notice: Clipped Content: View is clipping its content
```

How would I be able to find the item Xcode is referring to or make the warning go away? I attempted the suggestion from the accepted answer of one question (opening the .nib file as "source code"), but I don't get that option when control-clicking on the filename.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance!